# Show that $E(|X-a|) = \int_{-\infty}^a P(X < x) \, dx + \int_a^\infty P(X > x) \, dx$

Tags: probability

How to show:

$E(|X-a|) = \int_{-\infty}^a P(X < x) \, dx + \int_a^\infty P(X > x) \, dx$.

I have:

$$E(|X-a|) = \int |X-a| \, dP = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x-a| P_X(dx) = \int_{(-\infty,a)} a-x P_X(dx) + \int_{(a,\infty)} x-a P_X(dx)$$

But I do not see where to go. And how do I get to the Riemann-Integral? It is just $E(|X|)<\infty$ known, but nothing about an density function (in this case I would know how to get to the Riemann integral).

---

$$E(|X-a|) = \int_{(0,\infty)} P(|X-a| > t) \lambda(dt) = \int_{(0,\infty)} P(\max(X-a,0)+\max(a-X,0) > t) \lambda(dt)$$

This gives, since the events are disjoint, and with Rieman-integrability:

$$E(|X-a|) = \int_0^{\infty} P(\max(X-a,0) > t) + P(\max(a-X,0) > t) dx$$

How to go on? Integral is linear, but I do not know how separating them would help..

---

Finally it is first proven that:

$E(|X|) = \int_{-\infty}^0 P(X < x) \, dx + \int_0^\infty P(X > x) \, dx$.

Now I want to conclude for $|X-a|$.

$E(|X-a|) = \int_{-\infty}^0 P(X-a < x) \, dx + \int_0^\infty P(X-a > x) \, dx$
$= \int_{-\infty}^0 P(X < x+a) \, dx + \int_0^\infty P(X > x+a) \, dx$
$= \int_{-\infty}^a P(X < x) \, dx + \int_a^\infty P(X > x) \, dx$

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be easier if we start from the formula 
$$\mathbb E(Y)=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathbb P\{Y>t\}\mathrm dt,$$
where $Y$ is a non-negative random variable.

Then notice that for a real number $x$, we have $|x|=\max\{x,0\}+\max\{0,-x\}$.

Making a substitution $u=x-a$ in the two integral in the RHS of the equality we want to prove, we notice that we can assume that $a=0$.

We thus have 
$$\mathbb E|X|=\mathbb E\max\{X,0\}+\mathbb E\max\{0,-X\}.$$
We have for $t>0$
$$\{\max\{X,0\}>t\}=\{X>t\}$$
and 
$$\{\max\{-X,0\}>t\}=\{X<-t\},$$
hence we get the result integrating.

Comment: I do not know how to continue from there.

Comment: @FerdinandLampe See edit.

Comment: Gosh. Thank you! So I see this for $a=0$ now. How exactly is the argument, that it suffices to show that equality for $a=0$? I kind of first though, ok, I see, but in the end, I'm to stupid to see, how then the equality follows for every $a$, where the integral-bonudaries are changed accordingly..

Comment: Assume that you showed it when $a=0$. Then consider $Y:=X-a$. Then do the substitutions.

Comment: I'm confused since I'm not subsituting the integrated variable. It should be alright now in my question edit?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, for a positive variable, I think of
$$
\mathrm{E}(Y)=-\int_0^\infty x\,\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}P(Y\ge x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Since $-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}P(Y\ge x)$ is the probability density of $Y$ being near $x$. $P(Y\ge x)$ is monotonic decreasing and so it is differentiable almost everywhere. If $P(Y\ge x)$ is not differentiable everywhere, we can use the [Riemann-Stieltjes Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) and define
$$
\mathrm{E}(Y)=-\int_0^\infty x\,\mathrm{d}P(Y\ge x)
$$

Integration by parts, which is valid for the Riemann-Stieltjes integral, yields
$$
\mathrm{E}(Y)=-\lim_{x\to\infty}x\,P(Y\ge x)+\int_0^\infty P(Y\ge x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Summation by parts gives
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}(Y)
&\ge\sum_{k=0}^\infty2^k\left(P(Y\ge2^k)-P(Y\ge2^{k+1})\right)\\
&=2^0P(Y\ge2^0)+\sum_{k=0}^\infty(2^{k+1}-2^k)P(Y\ge2^{k+1})\\
&=P(Y\ge1)+\sum_{k=0}^\infty2^kP(Y\ge2^{k+1})
\end{align}
$$
Since the summation converges, $2^kP(Y\ge2^k)\to0$. Therefore, since $P(Y\ge x)$ is monotonic non-increasing, we get
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}x\,P(Y\ge x)=0
$$
Therefore,
$$
\mathrm{E}(Y)=\int_0^\infty P(Y\ge x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
For $\mathrm{E}(|X-a|)$, this becomes,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}(|X-a|)
&=\int_0^\infty P(|X-a|\ge x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_a^\infty P(X\ge x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{-\infty}^a P(X\le x)\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$

Comment: No need to assume the random variable is continuous.  For nonnnegative $X$, set  $I(x) = 1_{\{X > x\}|}$.  Then  $X = \int_0^\infty I(x) dx$.  Take the expectation on both sides;  Tonelli's theorem allows the interchange of integral and expectation.

Comment: @StephenHerschkorn: Thanks. That is cleaner, but I didn't know how much background to assume. I presented what I thought was close to the level of the question, but I miss sometimes.

Comment: Oho, do not really see throug this one. Why do I know that $P(Y>x)$ is differentiable?

Comment: @FerdinandLampe In general it is not (differentiable). Which is why one should study and adopt the Tonelli approach to this specific question and to tons of similar ones, it being more powerful and more rigorous.

Comment: @FerdinandLampe: Since $P(Y\ge x)$ is monotonic decreasing, it is differentiable almost everywhere. If it is not differentiable, one can use the Riemann-Stieltjes integral, as I have added above.

Comment: @robjohn Why not use at the onset that E(Y) is the integral of P(Y>x), a formula you finally arrive at, whose (fully rigorous) proof is much simpler than what you explain (and does not require that Y is integrable).

Comment: @Did: because I had thought that $\mathrm{E}(Y)=\int P(Y\ge x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ was part of the question. If that were a given, the answer would indeed be far simpler.

Comment: OK. In that case you could show the "right" proof of this formula.

Comment: @Did: I agree that the proof outlined by Stephen Herschkorn above is a cleaner proof. However, it requires certain prerequisites; e.g. familiarity with integration of functions whose values are a random variable, such as $\mathbf{1}_{\{X\gt x\}}$. Instead, I was paralleling the proof in analysis that $\int_X|f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty \mu\{x\in X:|f(x)|\gt\lambda\}\,\mathrm{d}\lambda$, which is, in essence, the same.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the integrands are monotone.  And therefore (improperly) Riemann integrable.

Comment: Ok, more or less I got this one. But anyhow, I do not know how to continue (wether its now Riemann or not) with altering the equation.. I do not know how monotony of integrand implies Riemann integrable. I just know the thing on compact intervals and then Riemann=Lebesgue..

Comment: Well, the limit (as endpoints go to $\infty$) of the Lebesgue integrals is your answer (possibly $+\infty$) so that is also the (improper) Riemann integral.